# how to stop spring security timeout from loading my login page in a div

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am having an issue with spring security's timeout facility. On my home JSP i have a table. each list item will allow the user to modify the data in this list element. when you click the edit icon a modal opens with the data from that list element so the user can edit it. the issue I am having is if this modal is open and the system times out and loads the login page. but it loads the login page into the table div. I am just wondering if anyone knows of any possible solutions to this problem?? I have increased the time out limit but will not fix the problem of the login page being displayed in my table div. any help is much appreciated.

hanks in advance Billy

Comment: I'm not what you mean by ```loads the login page```. Usually if you timeout, Spring will actually send a redirect response to your client. Whatever is receiving these requests on your behalf (likely a browser) is probably automatically following those redirects, so it seems like the login page gets returned as the data. You should double check that the the response is not a redirected response prior to rendering the data. (Also, you should probably set an *idle timeout* if you expect the timeout to get refreshed every time you make a request with the current session.)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check via javascript if the returned page is a login form and in that case open the proper login page, then retrieve the original url after a successful login.

An example is here: http://gal-levinsky.blogspot.it/2011/08/spring-security-3-ajax-login.html